# Coalesce private function for PHP?

Tags: php

Hello I have this function that sometimes the parameter
Product $product causes an error because it comes null.
I need that if this causes an error the Product parameter $product is assigned this variable $product2 which will always get a value.

I need to do it on the function line to avoid editing many lines that call this function.

Can be done?

Example

Code

```
private static function StockStatus($objProduct, Product $product, $infolasterroredu = false)
{
//code
}
```

i need something like this

```
private static function StockStatus($objProduct, Product $product ?: $product2, $infolasterroredu = false)
{
//code
}
```

This would be the **Product** class

```
<?php

namespace ExternalImporter\application\libs\pextractor\parser;

defined('\ABSPATH') || exit;

class Product {

    public $link;
    public $domain;
    public $title;
    public $description;
    public $price;
    public $currencyCode;
    public $image;
    public $oldPrice;
    public $manufacturer;
    public $inStock;
    public $availability;
    public $category;
    public $condition;
    public $ratingValue;
    public $reviewCount;
    public $features = array();
    public $images = array();
    public $reviews = array();
    public $paused;
    public $categoryPath = array();
    public $extra = array();

}
```

Currently when calling I get an error when it is null. How could I correct it?

Comment: Where is $product2 declared at?

Comment: In the function call that's why I need to add in the static function somehow in case Product $product fails. See the second example for reference.

Comment: Where is `$product2` declared?

Comment: Are you saying that the value you pass in can be null? If that is an OK value to get, change the definition from `Product $product` to `?Product $product` and the method will accept `null` as an argument. You will still need to check if the value is null or not before trying to use that variable in the method though. If it requires to get an instance of Product, then you should sort that out when you call the method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can make argument nullable with `?` before the type, so you don't get an error

If there could be a different type comming in you will also get an error, then you can remove the type from the argument and check if is the desired type inside the function

```
private static function StockStatus($objProduct, $product, $infolasterroredu = false)
{
    //Check if $product is Product
    if(!($product instanceof Product)) {
        //Do something if it's not type Product
        $product = $product2;
    }
    

    //code
}
```

Comment: I get this error Apparently the question mark doesn't override the error.
1.- Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to 
2.- instance of stdClass given, called in

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the method? I also think the error you shared is missing some words

Comment: @Club That error is saying that you're padding a class that is NOT a `Product` but is a `stdClass`

Comment: I understand how I could call Product $product but inside the function?

Comment: You had stated the error was because  product came null, but it appears to be stdClass instead, you could remove the type from the argument to remove the error, then check type or null inside function.

Comment: If ok then how could I call "Product $product" inside the function and not before?

Comment: I updated my answer to check $product class inside function

Comment: It works but is there any way to declare if it exists? Since in your example you only check if it does not exist but if it does exist it is not declared. PD: I appreciate all your time.

Comment: Do you mean if check for null? try this `if ($product) { //not null }`

Comment: Dear @Manuvo edit the question and add the class.
How could I edit this class so that it does not generate the error and be able to use the null operator?

Comment: Dear @Manuvo I need to do it through the direct function and not in the calls, this would take me to edit many lines of code.

That's why I need to improve the function call.
Add the class that executes and generates the error to the question.